# Is there a way to read Stata labels in python?

Tags: python, pandas, stata

```
df = pd.read_stata('file.dta')
for cols in df.columns.values:
    name = cols.lower()
    type = df[cols].dtype
    #label = ...
```

I need to get the labels/descriptions in python for each column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this

```
reader = pd.io.stata.StataReader('file.dta')
header = reader.variable_labels()
for var in header:
    name = var
    label = header[name]
```

Comment: I was about to comment on typo, but you fixed it.  I am not sure what you were trying to do with the `for` loop though (?) as "header" is already a dictionary.  Btw in retrospect I would have just done my answer as a comment but it got two quick upvotes so I decided to leave it.

Comment: Yes, I was writing it in a csv file row by row and then doing a little more manipulations with it. But yes..thanks for your input! :)

Answer (score 9):

In Pandas 0.22, you can also access this by creation of the iterator. I.e.

```python
import pandas as pd
itr = pd.read_stata('file.dta', iterator=True)
itr.variable_labels()
```

This will return a dictionary where the keys are variable names and the values are variable labels. I think this is easier to remember than `pd.io.stata.StataReader`.

Answer (score 5):

This will return a dictionary of labels:

```
>>> pd.io.stata.StataReader('file.dta').variable_labels()
{'x': 'x label', 'y': 'y label'}
```

Comment: `reader`  is not defined in that answer so it wasn't clear where it came from. From your answer it seems it is from pd.io so that means something new for me. :)

Comment: Ah, yes, good point!  Thanks!  I presume it was just a typo (now fixed, btw), but I'm happy to have added something of value in any event.